# Create dynamic n1ql query of Couchbase, but it's not returning records and gracefully exiting without any error

Tags: go, migration, couchbase

This is how am creating dynamic n1ql in my code:

```
    queryString :="select meta().id,round((META().cas)/1000000000) as maxCAS,Expires from `" + configuration.BucketName + "` where APPID='"+configuration.APPID+"' "
    queryString += "LIMIT $Limit_value "
    queryString += "offset $offest_value; "
    
    params := make(map[string]interface{})
    params["Limit_value"] = Limit_value
    params["offest_value"] = offest_value
    
    rows, err := cluster.Query(queryString,&gocb.QueryOptions{NamedParameters: params})
       if err != nil { panic(err) }
    for rows.Next() {  // not reaching this loop after adding n1ql dynamic code
      fmt.Println("row value reached loop :",rows)
        err := rows.Row(&row)
            if err != nil { 
               panic(err)   
               }
        fmt.Println("row value :",row)
// remaining code //
```

I checked in PCAP, integer values are substituted in place of limit and offset but n1ql query is not getting executed when dynamically prepared not providing me the records (same code works fine if n1ql passed as not dynamic). Can anyone please help me to solve this issue? There is no error in the code it's graceful exit.

PCAP Content:

```
JavaScript Object Notation: application/json
    Object
        Member Key: $Limit_value
            String value: 20000
            Key: $Limit_value
        Member Key: $offest_value
            String value: 680000
            Key: $offest_value
        Member Key: auto_execute
            True value
            Key: auto_execute
        Member Key: client_context_id
            String value: 6bca72f7-955b-4d0c-ac2d-d38d3a7e30e9
            Key: client_context_id
        Member Key: metrics
            False value
            Key: metrics
        Member Key: statement
            String value: PREPARE select meta().id,round((META().cas)/1000000000) as maxCAS,Expires from `golang3` where APPID='testData' LIMIT $Limit_value offset $offest_value; 
            Key: statement
        Member Key: timeout
            String value: 1m14.999950043s
            Key: timeout
```

Comment: It says no index available  make sure index available .  In UI EXPLAIN SELECT meta().id,round((META().cas)/1000000000) as maxCAS,Expires from `golang3`  WHERE APPID=$1 LIMIT 1;

Comment: index are available . only through golang code $1 value not being picked properly so am facing this issue

Comment: i modified my code as below , but limit and offset value as integer not being picked , how can i pass integer value dynamically to my n1ql query

Comment: IMPORT (
"gopkg.in/couchbase/gocb.v2"
)
queryString :="select meta().id,round((META().cas)/1000000000) as 
maxCAS,Expires from `" + configuration.BucketName + "` where 
APPID='"+configuration.APPID+"' "
queryString += "LIMIT $Limit_value "
queryString += "offset $offest_value; "

params := make(map[string]interface{})
params["Limit_value"] = Limit_value   // BOTH offest_value AND Limit_value   are 
integer variables 
params["offest_value"] = offest_value

rows, err := cluster.Query(queryString,&gocb.QueryOptions{NamedParameters: params})

Comment: Hi Syeda, it's difficult to read code in the comments. Can you please edit your question to include the modified code?